# Can't access NGINX server in local network

Tags: nginx, local, linux-mint

I'm unable to connect to my nginx server hosted on my Linux Mint Distro through other local machines. I can connect fine through localhost or 127.0.0.1 on the same computer.

On my phone if I type in the local IP of the computer in Chrome/Firefox shows up as "Unable to connect". I can ping the computer and receive data back, and vice versa, but nginx will not connect.

The local IP is 192.168.1.54 and the IP of my phone is 192.168.1.56

Tried using server_name 192.168.1.54 and server_name 192.168.1.56, none worked.

Tried enabling ufw and adding http and https as rules, didn't work. Still unable to connect. I'm stumped.

```
        # Default server configuration
    #
    server {
        #listen 80 default_server;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server;

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/test;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

    }
```

"Unable to connect" when typing in the nginx server's IP address in the browser from other local machines on the same network.

No error messages or access logs show up when attempts are made in /var/log/nginx/

Comment: Have you added the rules via command line or via the files of ufw?

Comment: In terminal: sudo ufw enable, sudo ufw allow http, sudo ufw allow https

Comment: Have you tried pinging that device from another local computer?

Comment: Yes I mentioned being able to ping it in the second paragraph. I found a temporary solution: sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j Accept however I need to run this every time my computer restarts. I want a solution where I don't have to do that because I want it working just through the ufw rules. I'm honestly stumped, something seems messed up with my iptables configuration and I don't know what.

Comment: Four years later, I'm having the same problem. Have you found a solution?